# how to get column values to comma seperatedly including id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a requirement where my current table has

```
id     value
1      newyork
1      boston
1      dallas
```

I need the following output

```
id      value
1       newyork, boston, dallas
```

Comment: Why do you need it like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @YourTable table(ID int,[value] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'newyork'),
(1,'boston'),
(1,'dallas')

Select A.ID
      ,Value  = (Select Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +value From @YourTable Where ID=A.ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
 From (Select Distinct ID From @YourTable) A
```

Returns

```
ID  Value
1   boston,dallas,newyork
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but there is a small issue I lost the order in my result, how can I keep the order same as in table? appreciate all your efforts.

Comment: @sqlvan There is no inherent row order unless you have another key .  If you remove the DISTINCT they will come in order of the table variable, but you run the risk of dupes